# Android library project cannot be launched?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I am totally confused by this error message: `Android library projects cannot be launched.`

I carefully checked the `build path` and `library`, everything is `"OK"`. And there is no error in Problems view. However, when I tried to run my application as an Android project, it failed and showed this message.

already i have set library in properties check. my build Path also all are fine. when run my application error message is coming.In my application i have added `Google play service library`

please tell me any suggestions.

Comment: Your project is Library project?

Comment: just go to project property and unselected the library project checkbox

Comment: You're not accidentally attempting to run a source file which is contained within the library, are you? I run into this in Eclipse, when working on my own libs. I sometimes forget which source file I have open and just hit run. If its a source file from the lib, you'll always see this message. Just a thought.

Comment: yes my project is Library project

Comment: thanku guy now it's working when unselected the library checkbox

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just uncheck the Is library from project properties.

[image]

Comment: After selecting the checkbox still the same error is showing... Is there any other option

Answer (score 2):

go to project property file and Remove this line -
android:library=true;

Answer (score 0):

just remove your library file and then goto the ---   project > property > android > remove library > add new library > apply ...  then